# Files in a (apparently) non-existent directory take disk space

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

**TL;DR: Files exist and take space in a diretory that's nowhere to be found.**

So... I got a little problem here. This all is happening on Windows 8.1, I had no issues on my Win7 PC.

Yesterday I downloaded some Anime-Episodes with xdcc-catcher (and yes I do know now that this isn't exactly welcome in those channels, but.. that's not the point). Those files were apparently downloaded to the default directory, which should be "c:\program files (x86)\xdcc catcher\downloads" (note the lowercase path, xdcc catcher forces this..).

Now I tried finding this folder in Windows Explorer, but it doesn't exist. In the "xdcc catcher" directory there are only 2 folders and 2 files, even though there should be more.

When I rightclick the downloaded file in xdcc-catcher and try to open it, WMP pops up and trys playing the file (though it can't, cause it's an mkv). It seems WMP is finding the file, since it can see a file it can't decode and gives the proper error message (this might be due to the file-ending provided though, I don't know how WMP works).

I then went into Power Shell and tried finding the files there, with no success, `ls` only lists the same files/folders Explorer does.

I tried booting Mac (Win8.1 is on a BootCamp Drive), but same situation there. Tried Ubuntu 12.04 Live Boot, no luck there. I tried scanning with jDiskReport to see if there's space taken up, directory isn't shown.

Problem is, I know those files do take disk-space (I tried it, downloaded some more files and free disk-space went down accordingly).

I have absolutely no idea what to do anymore... I can't delete them, I can't use them, I can't move them. I tried googling around, but all I found was the occasional "can't delete file but it appears in explorer" thingy. But as said, that's not my issue, I got it the other way round.

I tried creating the directory where i's supposed to be, and it's created, but empty. Windows search doesn't find them either (I read in another thread that those files would sometimes appear in search).

Any ideas except formatting drive? I just came back from complete reinstall of Win 8.1 x)

Comment: Take a look at this, maybe this is what is happening: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005081/how-to-detect-file-redirection-to-the-windows-virtualstore

Comment: @TheUser1024 You're a genius... I never thought of this... But yes, this was the issue ... Can't mark it as correct though since it's a comment, not an answer ;)

Comment: Glad my shot in the semi-dark hit and helped. You're welcome. ;-) I will turn it into a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows System Folders like `Program Files(x86)` are not supposed to be written to by programs outside of the installation. Since Vista there is the `Virtual Store` to catch these write operations. Details can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005081/how-to-detect-file-redirection-to-the-windows-virtualstore

Your files can be found in the corresponding subfolder of (replace `Username`with yours): `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)`